# Using rev() *after* map() changes the behaviour of map() in rust

Tags: rust, iterator, mapping, slice, reverse

In writing code with iterators, I managed to find this behaviour:

```rust
fn main() {
    let slice = &[1, 2, 3, 4];
    
    println!("Just map");
    let mut max_so_far = 0;
    let _ = slice.iter().map(|&n| {max_so_far = max_so_far.max(n); println!("{}",max_so_far); 0}).last();
    
    println!("Reverse after map (shouldn't change map direction, but does)");
    max_so_far = 0;
    let _ = slice.iter().map(|&n| {max_so_far = max_so_far.max(n); println!("{}",max_so_far); 0}).rev().last();
}
```

Producing this output:

```
Just map
1
2
3
4
Reverse after map (shouldn't change map direction, but does)
4
4
4
4
```

This is an issue for me, as I need to traverse the slice backwards keeping track of the highest value so far for calculations, before reversing the output again, but using rev().map().rev() causes the map to traverse the slice forwards rather than backwards. How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: if you need process at rev but have result not in rev you need an intermediate storage of values result you have no choice here, math win. So you need to rev, collect result into a vector and then manipulate result vector like you want.

Comment: Why would `rev` after `map` _not_ change direction? That's quite literally what it does. The reverse of a mapped iterator is conceptually pretty much the same thing as the mapping of a reversed iterator.

Comment: @cdhowie true for pure functions, but if the mapping depends on and mutates some external state then the order could matter